# Can I change a Boolean type Model class attribute (and other attributes that aren't Fields)?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've been learning a bit of Django by using Eric Matthes's *Python Crash Course  *and stumbled upon the following problem. Namely, I had this code:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    public_2 = False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Then, in a view function, if I set `public = True` and `public_2 = True`, verifying in the shell, I would have `topic.public = True`, but `public_2 = False`. Why is this and is there any way to change the `public_2` attribute? Here's the view function:

```
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, id=topic_id)
    if topic.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.public = True
            new_entry.public_2 = True
            new_entry.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic',
                                                args=[topic_id]))

    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)
```

If there is no way to change this, are there other limitations on what types of attributes of the Model class can be changed?

Comment: Sorry, did not get your question. Usually django model is associated with Database, the attributes should be fields, which is directly stored in DB.

Comment: @ruddra, I was trying to change the value of `topic.public_2`, where topic is an instance of the Topic class, and couldn't do it. So I was wondering if it's possible, and if not, why not. Printing out `topic.public_2` does produce the value of `False`, so the variable definitely is associated with a value, and I'm just puzzled by why the latter can't be changed.